# Insert raw JSON into MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is there a way to insert JSON directly into MongoDB, without converting to a POJSO first?

Something like:

```
const myJSON = '{"foo":"bar"}';

db.collection.insert(myJSON, {raw:true}, (err, result) => {});
```

does anyone know how to do this? I am trying to avoid calling JSON.parse() on a JSON string only to have to serialized immediately afterward by the MongoDB driver.

Answer (score -1):

For insert raw json you need to add field name on which raw json store

```
db.collection.insert({ rawJason: myJSON }, { raw: true }, (err, data) => {})
```

`{ raw: true }` is optional

Comment: You can read [insert](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#insert) doc from here. raw true return all BSON documents as Raw Buffer documents. No more details about raw..